# Determining binary/text file type in Java?

Tags: java, file, text, binary

Namely, how would you tell an archive (jar/rar/etc.) file from a textual (xml/txt, encoding-independent) one?

Comment: Trick question - they're all binary files.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's no guaranteed way, but here are a couple of possibilities:

1. Look for a header on the file.  Unfortunately, headers are file-specific, so while you might be able to find out that it's a RAR file, you won't get the more generic answer of whether it's text or binary.
2. Count the number of character vs. non-character types.  Text files will be mostly alphabetical characters while binary files - especially compressed ones like rar, zip, and such - will tend to have bytes more evenly represented.
3. Look for a regularly repeating pattern of newlines.

Answer (score 14):

Using Java 7 Files class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType(java.nio.file.Path)

```
boolean isBinaryFile(File f) throws IOException {
        String type = Files.probeContentType(f.toPath());
        if (type == null) {
            //type couldn't be determined, assume binary
            return true;
        } else if (type.startsWith("text")) {
            return false;
        } else {
            //type isn't text
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That just checks on the file extension and not the file content and hence useless.

Comment: That is dependent on what's installed, according to the docs.

Comment: @ares actually it doesn't just check the file extension at all

Comment: you can remove the file extension and retry.

Answer (score 13):

I made this one.
A bit simpler, but for latin-based languages, it should work fine, with the ratio adjustment.

```
/**
 *  Guess whether given file is binary. Just checks for anything under 0x09.
 */
public static boolean isBinaryFile(File f) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
    int size = in.available();
    if(size > 1024) size = 1024;
    byte[] data = new byte[size];
    in.read(data);
    in.close();

    int ascii = 0;
    int other = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        byte b = data[i];
        if( b < 0x09 ) return true;

        if( b == 0x09 || b == 0x0A || b == 0x0C || b == 0x0D ) ascii++;
        else if( b >= 0x20  &&  b <= 0x7E ) ascii++;
        else other++;
    }

    if( other == 0 ) return false;

    return 100 * other / (ascii + other) > 95;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this function. One thing I'm having trouble figuring out is what is going on with the return value:
`return (ascii + other) * 100 / other > 95;`
Which, unless I'm missing something, will always return true: Mostly, the size will be `1024`, as will `data.length` and therefore `(ascii + other)`. 
So if `(ascii + other) * 100 == 102400`
then `102400 / other > 95`=>`102400 > 95 * other`=>`other < 1078`
Which means there needs to be more than 1078 (out of 1024) "other"s for this to return false, obviously impossible. 
Did you mean?: 
`(other / size * 100 > 95)`
Or am I missing something?

Comment: Cool cool. Ya, I ended up going with that too. Thanks again :)

Comment: Fails for UTF-16 LE, UTF-16 BE, UTF-8 with BOM

Comment: @rince That's possible, feel free to edit to enhance for BOM. Not sure if covering UTF 16 wouldn't inflate it to full-blown context characters parser...

Comment: Your algorithm has detected javascript files as binary. I think more binary compars could solve it. Meanwhile, @Michael von Wenckstern is working better for this propose at that time.

Comment: It is possible that it detects various files as binary. You always need to apply the particular set of characters used, and the particular encoding, and most importantly, your custom view on what's a text file. For instance, is a RTF a text file? Is PostScript a text file? Is a multi-part MIME encoded content a text file? ...

Comment: @RatataTata could you please provide your JavaScript file?

Answer (score 12):

Run `file -bi {filename}`. If whatever it returns starts with 'text/', then it's non-binary, otherwise it is. ;-)

Comment: It seems like there's "application/javascript" and "application/xml" also. Looking here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type suggests that it's not that simple.

Comment: You can check with `file -i {filename}` and check there ISN'T `charset=binary`.

Comment: I have to say I wasn't completely serious when I answered the above. Text files are just binary files interpreted in a particular way. If you meant if something is US-ASCII, then you could check every byte and see if it fits your definition of text. But perhaps you meant *any* type of character encoding. That's going to be a lot harder. Especially if you factor in the ones that are using say entropy based encoding (characters occurring often requiring less bits). At the other hand, if you meant everything US-ASCII, then a Base64 encoded image would also be text?

Comment: From the Hunting of the Snark: So the Bellman would cry: and the crew would reply "They are merely conventional signs!"

Comment: On macOS, I saw with `file --help` that `-bI` should be used to output the mime type and charset, instead of `-bi`, which only output 'regular file'.

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at the [JMimeMagic](https://github.com/arimus/jmimemagic) library.

> jMimeMagic is a Java library for
>   determining the MIME type of files or
>   streams.

Comment: Interesting library, but how is that going to help? It tells you the mime type, but not whether it's binary or text.

Comment: @Adam I don't understand your question? You can deduce from the MIME type itself whether the file is binary or not, right? I.e. if the type is `text/plain` it should be a textual file.

Comment: OK, I was being blunt. What I meant is that you still have to write extra logic to interpret the mime type as binary or text. 'text/plain' is not the only text-based mime type.

Comment: @Adam yes, think so too, concerning that i.e. `application/json` is also a textual representation. But referring to the original question, which was quite unspecific, I think this should suffice as a starting point :)

Answer (score 6):

**I used this code and it works for English and German text pretty well:**

```
private boolean isTextFile(String filePath) throws Exception {
    File f = new File(filePath);
    if(!f.exists())
        return false;
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
    int size = in.available();
    if(size > 1000)
        size = 1000;
    byte[] data = new byte[size];
    in.read(data);
    in.close();
    String s = new String(data, "ISO-8859-1");
    String s2 = s.replaceAll(
            "[a-zA-Z0-9ßöäü\\.\\*!\"§\\$\\%&/()=\\?@~'#:,;\\"+
            "+><\\|\\[\\]\\{\\}\\^°²³\\\\ \\n\\r\\t_\\-`´âêîô"+
            "ÂÊÔÎáéíóàèìòÁÉÍÓÀÈÌÒ©‰¢£¥€±¿»«¼½¾™ª]", "");
    // will delete all text signs

    double d = (double)(s.length() - s2.length()) / (double)(s.length());
    // percentage of text signs in the text
    return d > 0.95;
}
```

Comment: The idea is interesting, but instead of replaceAll, which needlessy creates a new string, I'd simply use a for loop to count text vs non-text characters. Putting the limit at 1000 characters means that it won't be *too* costly anyway, but it's still an useless cost

Answer (score 4):

If the file consists of the bytes 0x09 (tab), 0x0A (line feed), 0x0C (form feed), 0x0D (carriage return), or 0x20 through 0x7E, then it's probably ASCII text.

If the file contains any other ASCII control character, 0x00 through 0x1F excluding the three above, then it's probably binary data.

UTF-8 text follows a very specific pattern for any bytes with the high order bit, but fixed-length encodings like ISO-8859-1 do not. UTF-16 can frequently contain the null byte (0x00), but only in every other position.

You'd need a weaker heuristic for anything else.

Comment: checking for any occurrence of 0x10..0x1f might be the most simple option to detect binary?

Answer (score 3):

Just to let you know, I've chosen quite a different path. I my case, there are only 2 types of files, chances that any given file will be a binary one are high. So

1. presume that file is binary, try doing what's supposed to be done (e.g. deserialize)
2. catch exception
3. treat file as textual
4. if that fails, something is wrong with file itself

Comment: I think this is the best approach. Do you really care what the file type is? Or do you care whether you can do certain things with it. In many cases, if you can do those things, you don't need to actually know what the type is.

Answer (score 3):

You could try Apache Tika, I've opened a [request specifically for this feature](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-3409)

but for now, I think this might work... needs more thorough testing, may also have the problem of other mime type libraries in which you still really need a mapping from the type to whether or not it's binary.

```java
var config = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig();
var tika = new Tika( config );
var mimeTypes = config.getMimeRepository();

var mimetype = tika.detect(Path.of("my/foo"));
var rootType = mimeTypes.forName( mime ).getType().getType();
rootType.endsWith( "text" ); // text and x-text
```

Comment: You probably want to check the aliases and parent types too, that'll help you spot [xml is mostly text-based](https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/main/tika-core/src/main/resources/org/apache/tika/mime/tika-mimetypes.xml#L4849) or [JavaScript is text-based](https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/main/tika-core/src/main/resources/org/apache/tika/mime/tika-mimetypes.xml#L337)

Answer (score 2):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [DROID](http://droid.sourceforge.net/) tool.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the suggestion from xenoterracide, here is an implementation using Tika Core.

```java
    public boolean isText(byte[] contentBytes) {
        Tika tika = new Tika();
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(contentBytes);
        try {
            Set<MediaType> mediaTypes = new HashSet<>();
            MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse(tika.detect(byteArrayInputStream));
            MediaTypeRegistry mediaTypeRegistry = MediaTypeRegistry.getDefaultRegistry();
            while(mediaType != null) {
                mediaTypes.addAll(mediaTypeRegistry.getAliases(mediaType));
                mediaTypes.add(mediaType);
                mediaType = mediaTypeRegistry.getSupertype(mediaType);
            }
            return mediaTypes.stream().anyMatch(mt -> mt.getType().equals("text"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

There are several different Tika.detect methods you can use depending on if you are starting from a File, have a file name, etc. See https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.tika/tika-core/2.4.1/org/apache/tika/Tika.html