# Is there any way to check the given file is binary or human readable?

Tags: java, java-io

I have a file with some extension, at times it can be a binary format and at times it can be human readable. Both type of files have the same mimetype.

Comment: dupt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620993/determining-binary-text-file-type-in-java