# How to check if .properties file is a text file

Tags: java

I tried using Files.probeContentType, but it randomly returns null, and I've read its bugged on windows in java versions older then java 8. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620993/determining-binary-text-file-type-in-java

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov How is this valid in my case?

Comment: "Count the number of character vs. non-character types. Text files will be mostly alphabetical characters while binary files - especially compressed ones like rar, zip, and such - will tend to have bytes more evenly represented."

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Is there a simpler way though? Like is there a build in function for that? That is what I am looking for.

Comment: The question is very underspecified (as the other answers to that question show).

Answer (score 0):

> URLConnection.getContentType(), a method that "returns the value of
>   the content-type header field."

This worked fine for me:

```
 public String identifyFileTypeUsingUrlConnectionGetContentType(final String fileName)
    {
       String fileType = "Undetermined";
       try
       {
          final URL url = new URL("file://" + fileName);
          final URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
          fileType = connection.getContentType();
       }
       catch (MalformedURLException badUrlEx)
       {
          System.out.println("ERROR: Bad URL - " + badUrlEx);
       }
       catch (IOException ioEx)
       {
          System.out.println("Cannot access URLConnection - " + ioEx);
       }
       return fileType;
    }
```